# Automate splitting arrays to input into table in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array that contains a total of 56 numbers. I need to take the first 14 numbers, the next 14 numbers, etc. and create a table with 14 columns and 4 rows. The below code works, but I would like to automate the process with a for loop or another method so I can repeat the same process on arrays that are much longer. Any suggestions?

```
array2table([means(1:14);means(15:28);means(29:42);means(43:56)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reshape` to change the dimensions of your data prior to creating the table. We will reshape it to have `14` rows and `numel(means) / 14` columns and then take the transpose `.'` so that we instead have `numel(means) / 14` rows and `14` columns.

```
T = array2table(reshape(means, 14, []).');
```